# object not found Console C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to call a method that will send emails in a console application. The application works fine as windows service but they want me to change the windows service to a console application. Now the same method is giving me object reference not set.
below is my code

```
class Program
{
    const string title = "Email Manager Timer Job ";
    private static ActionManager Man;

    public static void  Main()
    {
        SendEmail();

        using (var task = new Model())
        {
            var cdrlTask = new ExternalTask(); 
            cdrlTask.Created = DateTime.Today;
            cdrlTask.Title = title;
            task.ExternalTasks.Add(cdrlTask);
            task.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public static void SendEmail()
    {            
        Man.SendEmails(); // ---> object not found here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not setting `Man` to an object before calling `.SendEmails()` on it. In order to call the `.SendEmails()` method on an object, you need to create an object to call it on.